# show data from sql server in datagridview combobox column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm new in DataGridView I'm usually using list view 
my program retrieve the data from sql server and show it in datagridview 
so how i can make  one of the column to be combobox and add subitems to it and show the current value in the combobox coming from the database ?

this is my code to show data :

```
Public Sub showGV()

    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM money_sent", Conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Using dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)

                'Set AutoGenerateColumns False
                MetroGrid2.AutoGenerateColumns = False

                'Set Columns Count
                MetroGrid2.ColumnCount = 12

                'Add Columns

                Dim bc As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
                bc.Tag = False
                bc.Text = "Delete"
                bc.Name = ""
                bc.Width = 25
                'MetroGrid1.Columns.Add(bc)
                MetroGrid2.Columns.Insert(0, bc)


                MetroGrid2.Columns(1).Name = "smoney"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(1).HeaderText = "المبلق المرسل"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "smoney"

                MetroGrid2.Columns(2).Name = "moneyt"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(2).HeaderText = "العملة"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "moneyt"

                MetroGrid2.Columns(3).Name = "commission"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(3).HeaderText = "العمولة"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "commission"

                MetroGrid2.Columns(4).Name = "rname"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(4).HeaderText = "أسم المستقبل"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(4).DataPropertyName = "rname"

                MetroGrid2.Columns(5).Name = "rphone"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(5).HeaderText = "هاتف المستقبل"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(5).DataPropertyName = "rphone"

                MetroGrid2.Columns(6).Name = "rcountry"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(6).HeaderText = "البلد المستقيل"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(6).DataPropertyName = "rcountry"

                MetroGrid2.Columns(7).Name = "sname"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(7).HeaderText = "أسم المستقبل"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(7).DataPropertyName = "sname"

                MetroGrid2.Columns(8).Name = "sphone"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(8).HeaderText = "هاتف المستقبل"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(8).DataPropertyName = "sphone"

                MetroGrid2.Columns(9).Name = "comname"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(9).HeaderText = "الشركة المستقبلة"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(9).DataPropertyName = "comname"

                MetroGrid2.Columns(10).Name = "date"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(10).HeaderText = "تاريخ الارسال"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(10).DataPropertyName = "date"

                MetroGrid2.Columns(11).Name = "note"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(11).HeaderText = "الملاحظات"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(11).DataPropertyName = "note"

                MetroGrid2.Columns(12).Name = "id"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(12).HeaderText = "id"
                MetroGrid2.Columns(12).DataPropertyName = "id"

                MetroGrid2.DataSource = dt

                Dim imageb As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
                imageb.Tag = False
                imageb.Text = "image"
                imageb.Name = ""
                imageb.Width = 25
                'MetroGrid1.Columns.Add(bc)
                MetroGrid2.Columns.Insert(10, imageb)

                Me.MetroGrid2.Columns("id").Visible = False
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

and this is the column that i want to make it combobox column :

```
   MetroGrid2.Columns(2).Name = "moneyt"
   MetroGrid2.Columns(2).HeaderText = "العملة"
   MetroGrid2.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "moneyt"
```

Comment: Run a `SELECT` query to just get the one column you need from the table, then fill a `DataTable` with the results, and set `combobox.DataSource = DataTable`

Comment: Start by creating a `DataGridViewComboboxColumn` for it.  use the datasource for the items or design it in the designer

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
This how I did it:

Sub FillGrid()
    Dim cbb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText ="العملة"}
    cbb.Items.Add("شيقل.ج")
    cbb.Items.Add("د.اردني")
    cbb.Items.Add("د.امريكي")
    cbb.Items.Add("يورو")
    cbb.Items.Add("ر.صيني")
    'ADD BUTTON
    Dim btnDelete As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
    Dim btnImage As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()

    MetroGrid2.Columns.Insert(0, btnDelete)
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "المبلغ المرسل")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Insert(2, cbb)
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "العمولة")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "أسم المستقبل")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "هاتف المستقبل")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "البلد المستقبل")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "أسم المرسل")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "هاتف المرسل")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "الشركة المستقبلة")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "تاريخ التسجيل")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Insert(11, btnImage)
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "الملاحظات")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "ID")
    MetroGrid2.Columns(13).Visible = False

    Const sql As String = "SELECT * FROM money_sent"
    Dim adt As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    adt.Fill(dt)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        MetroGrid2.Rows.Add()
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(1)
        Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DirectCast(MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(2), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        cell.Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(2)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(3)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(4)
        'DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = "DELETE"
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(5)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(6)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(7)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(8)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(9)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(10)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(12)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(0)
    Next

End Sub
```